# Regex to remove occurrences of a word from text, but leave only one space between each word

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Here's a problem I commonly encounter. I have a text file that contains words, one space between each word, and no spaces in the beginning or end of a line. I'd like to use e.g. sed to remove occurrences of a word, leaving only one space between each word, no spaces in the beginning or end of a line. Is this possible with one regular expression?

The best solution I can think of, requires three regular expressions.

```
% cat text
A B C A B C A

% sed -r 's/ ?\bA\b ?/ /g' text
 B C B C 

% sed -r 's/ ?\bA\b ?/ /g' text | sed 's/^ *//' | sed 's/ *$//'
B C B C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/\<A\>/,"");$1=$1}1' file
B C B C
```

The `$1=$1` is used to clean up the output so it only has one space between word after the `A`s are removed.

---

If you do like double/triple spacing to be intact in lines that does not have `A`, use this:

```
awk 'gsub(/\<A\>/,""){$1=$1}1' file
B C B C
```

It will only modify line with `A` in it

Edit:
Updated with word boundary, so it does not remove part of words.

Comment: I like both answers, but selected this because it requires me to type the word only once.

Answer (score 2):

With **sed**:

```
AMD$ sed -r 's/\bA | A$//g' File
B C B C
```

Here, we are removing `A` with a space. We cover the 2 possibilities (a. `A` at beginning or anywhere in between, b. `A` at end).

Comment: This will remove `A` from end of words. This `A BA C ARC B C A` should become `BA C ARC B C`, not `BC ARC B C`

Comment: No it wont... See the space before A. (hence only the last word A).

Comment: It will change `BA C` to `BC`- Op like to remove words, I guess not part of word.

Comment: Yes.. i was about to mention that...Edited the answer.. thanks

Comment: Now there's just one problem: If the file contains just one word, the one that should be removed, this regular expression won't remove it.